# Prove $\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\ln( k) \geq \sum ^{n}_{k=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1}\ln( k)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

hey I saw this inequalities in a soltion for some questions but I can't understand why this is true .
Can somebody give me a hint about how they did that ?
\begin{gather}
\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\sqrt{k} \geq \sum ^{n}_{k=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1}\sqrt{k}\\
 \notag\\
 \notag\\
\sum ^{n}_{k=1}\ln( k) \geq \sum ^{n}_{k=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1}\ln( k)
\end{gather}

Comment: I must be missing something: isn't $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor +1 \geq 1$ enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summand is nonnegative, so omitting terms cannot increase the sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} f(k) + \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n f(k)\ge 0 + \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}^n f(k)$$